# Xcode stops running when I don't watch it for a while. What's wrong?

Tags: macos, xcode

I am (trying to be) running Xcode 4.3.2. on Lion 10.7.3

I noticed that when I stop watching Xcode and walk away from the computer for a while (like half an hour or so), Xcode in the mean time stopped running and has to be started again.

I read a lot about Xcode on Lion being unstable. Is that what is happening to me? Is it that unstable?

Comment: Are you running Xcode with any projects, files, etc open when it quits or is it just Xcode is open, you come back to it and it is no longer open without a trace?

Comment: All it did was installing the command line tools. For some reason it had to download them and that took a while. I let it be with no window open. Twice I found it closed without a trace and the command line tools not installed. (They had to be downloaded again from the beginning.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the built in "undocumented" to non-developers feature of Lion called Automatic Termination that is causing Xcode to quit when you don't want it to.

As noted in "[Lion Is a Quitter](http://tidbits.com/article/12398)"

> Lion will quit your running applications behind your back if it decides it needs the resources, and if you don’t appear to be using them. The heuristic for determining whether an application is “in use” is very conservative: it must not be the active application, it must have no visible, non-minimized windows — and, of course, it must explicitly support Automatic Termination.

Comment: That is ridiculous. I don't mean your answer, but the design decision. I think Apple have lost their mind!

Comment: I just notice that Xcode has quit again...

Comment: That particular Lion defect appears to be the reason for the weird behaviour. Any idea how I can repair this?

Comment: Ya if you verify that by opening a file or project, etc in Xcode causes Xcode to stop quitting, then Automatic Termination is the cause, other wise it maybe something else.

Comment: It's the automatic termination all right. When Xcode is just downloading stuff, no window is open and that means Xcode is ready for auto termination at Lion's pleasure. Only the third time downloading the command line tools worked because I left the Preferences window open that time.

Comment: An operating system that not only FAILS to run a program but is actually meant to terminate the program... that must be a first. Apple have lost their mind.

Comment: I would report it as a bug in Xcode if Lion is auto terminating Xcode before it can download an add on. Clearly Xcode is not communicating to the OS that it is in the process of doing a task (like it should be) and should not be open to the option of being terminated until that task/s have been completed.

Comment: Ya the Lion Auto termination is a side effect of the iOS-ification of OS X, best we can do is provide constructive feedback to Apple.

Comment: The OS should not terminate any program. That's how it should work. I never saw this as a matter of opinion, I saw it as a part of the definition of a multitasking OS.

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm The auto-termination is supposed to work with the saving of state on quit so unused programs quit (and then take no processor or memory instead of some); when the user relaunches the program, it resumes as if it had never quit. This is a bug in Xcode; I think the auto-termination feature is a good idea. My parents leave apps open all the time and get confused when their iMac gets slow. Auto-termination keeps their machine fast and they don't have to think about quitting every app they're not using *ringt now*.

Comment: Mac OS X pages out applications that are not used. I have had Macs of all kinds of speeds and memory sizes and I have never experienced non-used but running programs making the computer any slower.

Comment: And why would your parents use Xcode and get confused when it continues running?

Comment: Andrew, Good news there is a away to disable auto-termination on Lion see this question/answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48780/is-there-a-way-to-disable-os-x-auto-termination-of-applications